# Drive encryption password stored by Ubuntu Gnome 3 16.04

Tags: gnome, hard-drive, password, encryption

Hi I'm new here this will be my first question.

I have external drives on which I use disc encryption standard LUKS with  EXT4 file sytem.
Thing is that I set up Ubuntu to remember passwords for these drives
and it worked for some time until today when Ubuntu asked me for password to access one of HDD. I remember password for my drive but I'm curious is there a time limit for storing these passwords in Ubuntu?